# MATLAB app designer: Share data between two apps (in startup function not using button to extract data in second app)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, properties, matlab-guide

Suppose that we have same example in [Share Data Among Multiple UI Figure Windows](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-across-callbacks-in-app-designer.html#busp3ol-15) in MATLAB documentation, but we don't have a plot button in second app. We want directly show data in axis in second app when we push calculate and share button (when we push calculate and share button in first app, the second app will open and show the plot).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method (function) in the plotting GUI object. This method can be called by the parent GUI and can execute the plotting in the same way as the button push call back.